# Need advice on JHipster SaaS type application

Tags: multi-tenant, jhipster, saas

I'm in the process of developping an application using JHipster that will be deployed as SaaS. 
I don't really know the path I need to take while generating and coding my project (monolithic/microservice+gateway/etc) i need you help.

Here is what I want :

- **Shared databases, differents schemas** with multi-tenancy for each companies (already got this working on an monolithic project using this method : http://anakiou.blogspot.fr/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html)
- Each companies have their own users
- A web-page for the user of a company to log in and be redirected to the application wich will be using the correct schema corresponding to the company (**the tenant is the company name**, should i use a "master" schema in database to store all the users  ?)
- Use liquibase to update **all schemas at once**.

Thanks

Comment: JHipster is not a universal tool, your use case is quite outside of its scope, I'm not sure what benefits you expect from using it here.

Answer (score 1):

For your login page you could use sub domain names: one per company name. If you own domain example.com you can assign company1.example.com to company1 and company2.example.com to company2. Wildcard DNS record could help.

Using nginx to define these virtual hosts, you could add an HTTP header to incoming requests to pass the company name to your app. This would enable you to adjust business logic and presentation to each company.